# A puzzled riddle

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme

What you see here  is plainly in sight
And nothing here  is made of letters
Give it a try -  what am I?
I'm everything  that is not quite right
Please forgive me  find what matters
Tell me, quick,  for sometimes I lie

> What you see here is not quite right

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I see you already took the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). I'm waiting to see how this riddle turns out!

Comment: I am confused, which is the actual part of riddle? Text above or text below **Give it a try - what am I?** Or may be we need to arrange the riddle to make it rhyme

Comment: @Techidiot, it rhymes already, in an ABCABC pattern.

Comment: @Hellion-Yeah noticed it.

Comment: Is there, maybe, a tag missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of lateral thinking, you are

> A Puzzled Riddle or Riddle

Taking the reasons's from [Leo's Answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46464/30887) with a little edit which I thought at the first look -

> The riddle is not arranged properly and hence is puzzled.

Content should have been like this

> What you see here is not quite right
>  And nothing here is plainly in sight
>  Give it a try - find what matters
>  I'm everything that is made of letters
>  Please forgive me for sometimes I lie
>  Tell me, quick, what am I?

Well Leo deserve's the votes for figuring out almost the right sequence/arrangements.

Answer (score 6):

Could you possibly be

> The whitespace between letters - in a browser multiple whitespaces show as one.

I'm guessing this as

> *On clicking edit* there are *two* whitespaces in the middle of each line.

What you see here is plainly in sight, 
And nothing here is made of letters, 
I'm everything that is not quite right

> True - it's in sight and not made of letters. Everything is the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> Words?

I'm not quite sure about the answer I got, but I think I've found the right approach:

> This riddle is composed by pieces which must be put in the right place, as in a puzzle

Doing this, I got:

> What you see here is not quite right
>
> And nothing here is plainly in sight
>
> Give it a try - find what matters
>
> I'm everything is made of letters
>
> Please forgive me for sometimes I lie
>
> Tell me, quick, what am I?

And this is where I'm not sure anymore. What I understood is:

> The first line is the same as the hint under the question, that's why I'm confident. Second and third line probably refer to the confusing way the original riddle is presented. The fourth line is the only one from which I could extract an hint of the final solution, that's why *words* is my guess. Fifth line confuses me, is it another reference to the starting riddle being a red herring? Or there's still something I'm missing? The last line is probably just a closing question, I don't think other hints are hidden in it.

Comment: That's what I thought when I left a comment on the question. +1 for the arrangements. I will borrow this into my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

More literal answer this time:

> LIGHT (or perhaps PHOTON).

*What you see here is plainly in sight*

> You need light in order for your sense of sight to work.

*And nothing here is made of letters*

> That wasn't just a letterplay clue ("in sight" meaning a letter of the word "sight").

*Give it a try - what am I?*
*I'm everything that is not quite right*

> "Not quite right" could refer to the weirdness of wave-particle duality, or to the fact that the word LIGHT is not quite the word RIGHT.

*Please forgive me find what matters*
*Tell me, quick, for sometimes I lie*

> "Lie" in a wave formation - or, again, wave-particle duality, light 'lying' about its very nature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe

> The Devil as a serpent?

In the riddle,

> one of the spaces between words of each line is actually two spaces (visible if you "edit" the question).  In monospace font the double spaces are much more obvious:
>
> ```
>     What you see here  is plainly in sight
>     And nothing here  is made of letters
>     Give it a try -  what am I?
>     I'm everything  that is not quite right
>     Please forgive me  find what matters
>     Tell me, quick,  for sometimes I lie
> ```
>
> The sinuous winding of the double-space gaps is reminiscent of a serpent.

In addition,

> What you see here  is plainly in sight
>      And nothing here  is made of letters

> tells us we're looking for something visible but not letters, so we know we're supposed to look at the spaces.

> I'm everything  that is not quite right
>      Tell me, quick,  for sometimes I lie

> The Devil stands for everything not right, and as a Serpent in the Garden of Eden lied to Eve to deceive her.  Looking at the spaces and seeing how they resemble a snake, and connecting the two, brings me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are

> A false statement.(lie?)

What you see here is plainly in sight
And nothing here is made of letters

> Everything is made up of letters here. (So, it is a false statement that nothing is made up of letters)

I'm everything that is not quite right

> A false statement is not right.

Please forgive me find what matters
Tell me, quick, for sometimes I lie

> A lie is what it is?